# How to list all the three-letter files in /etc that start with s?

Tags: linux

How to list all the three-letter files in /etc that start with s?

would it be

ls -d /etc/s*

or

ls -d /etc/s%%

since all the three-letter files is what I'm looking for.

edit*
ls -d /etc/s??

would the ?? represent the other two letters followed by 's'
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

firstly the pattern s?? is correct for three characters that start with 's', but s?? is a glob expression and the shell will expand it to whatever matches. In my case /etc has two folders /etc/ssh & /etc/ssl. This means your suggested command

```
ls -d /etc/s??
```

will get expanded by shell to

```
ls -d /etc/ssh /etc/ssl
```

which will then only list directory names themselves as that is what the -d instructs ls to do.
Unfortunately leaving out the -d will cause the content of any 3 lettered directory under /etc to be listed - which is also not what you want.

You may need to use find, but instruct it to not recursively search (-maxdepth 1), to look for files (-type f) and for names matching the pattern 's??' (-name 's??')

```
find /etc -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 's??'
```

Note also that I have enclosed the pattern in single quotes, this will prevent the shell from expanding the search pattern to any matching files before find sees it.